# Image onmouser in html

Tags: javascript, html, image, onmouseover

```
<img width="167" height="119" onmouseout="this.src='http://test.plexasys.com/vivid/wp/wp-content/files_mf/pixel36092.png'" 
 onmouseover="this.src='http://test.plexasys.com/vivid/wp/wp-content/files_mf/pixel360rollover53.png'" alt="baton" 
src="http://test.plexasys.com/vivid/wp/wp-content/files_mf/pixel36092.png">
```

I have written like this for image on `mouseover` for another image. it is working fine in my local system. but in the server on `mouseover` image loading slowly for the first time. second time on-wards working fine.

please find the link http://2014.vividrgblighting.com/products/

Comment: So what is the question? Do you want to know why it loads slowly the first time?

Answer (score 2):

The hover images are loading slowly the first time because they have to be loaded by the browser. They run quicker second time because the browser has cached them. You will need to preload all of the images using Javascript if you want them to be loaded automatically.